# Ripple animation java

Tags: java, swing, animation

I've been writing a simple animation using Swing where you have a JFrame and a ripple animation starts wherever the JFrame receives a mouse click. I use an inner Animation class that extends JPanel for each animation in case multiple animations have to be played at once(I don't know if this is the best way to do it). When I click, I add a new Animation to the JFrame and pass the coordinates of the click to the Animation. However, the Animation repaint / paintComponent methods aren't working. In my understanding, repaint should call the paint / paintComponent methods, but in troubleshooting these methods aren't even being accessed. So how can I get the paint method to execute? Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Ripples extends JFrame {
public Ripples() {
    // window
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Ripples");
    setBounds(250, 250, 1000, 1000);
    setVisible(true);
    addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            Animation animation = new Animation(e.getX(), e.getY());
            add(animation);
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Ripples demo = new Ripples();
}

class Animation extends JPanel{
    private int radius;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Timer timer;

    Animation(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        radius = 0;

        timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (radius > 200) {
                    resetRadius();
                    timer.stop();
                }
                increaseRadius();
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public void increaseRadius() {
        radius += 1;
    }

    public void resetRadius() {
        radius = 0;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(x - (radius / 2), y - (radius / 2), radius, radius);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I click, I add a new Animation to the JFrame and pass the coordinates of the click to the Animation. However, the Animation repaint / paintComponent methods aren't working.

By default Swing components have a default size of (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

When you add a component to a visible GUI you need to invoke the layout manager so the component can be given a size/location. The basic code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint(); // sometimes needed
```

In your case you are adding the Animation panel to the content pane of the frame so you need to revalidate() the frame.